# IllegalStateException between sendRedirect() and ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java

is there a solution to resolve the conflict between the use of `objectOutputStreamhere` and `sendRedirect()` !?

```
private void writeObjectStream(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    getQueryFromAttribute(request);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
        oos.writeObject(appInfo);
        oos.writeObject(serviceInfo);
        oos.writeObject(queriesMap);
        response.reset();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        IOUtil.closeQuietly(oos);
    }
}
```

and here i call it `writeObjectStream`

```
writeObjectStream(request, response);
    try {
        response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(appInfo.getUrl()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

i tried an other solution for this problem as follows :

```
private void writeObjectStream(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
        oos.writeChars("x");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        IOUtil.closeQuietly(oos, ois);
    }
}
```

the call of `writeObjectStream`  :

```
....    
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
            response.setHeader("Location", "www.sample.com");
            response.setHeader("Content-Length", "" + 500);
            writeObjectStream(request, response);
            return true;
        }
```

the problem of the this solution is that it launch a  `java.io.EOFException` in the server side when i try to do  `ois = new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP, hyper-text transfer protocol, sends header lines (parameter name, colon, value), a numerical return code (200 OK, 304 REDIRECT), and then an empty line followed by the content (like the HTML page, or an image).

`sendRedirect` now outputs a header line with redirect location and the redirect return code. Then actually no more content follows.

In Java EE when you start writing, either text (`response.getWriter()`), or binary data (`response.getOutputStream()`), *all* headers must already have been written. Trying to Write a header later gives an error. *(Mitigated a bit by buffering, when the first buffer is still unwritten, but one may not count on that.)*

So your usage is a bit impossible. You send back binary data, serialized java objects? To the browser? And at the same time want the browser to switch to another URL - afterwards.

If you have JavaScript sending an AJAX request, then you might send your own type of header line first:

```
response.setHeader("AfterwardsGoTo", "http://reta-vortaro.de");
```

And then write the binary data.

Comment: so it's impossible !! 
I will try to find another way to do it 
tnks

Answer (score 2):

write *return* statement after *sendRedirect*

```
   response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(appInfo.getUrl()));
   return;
```

Accroding to [HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29)

> If the response has already been committed, this method throws an IllegalStateException.After using this method, the response should be 
>   considered to be committed and should not be written to.

You are also calling the `reset()`.If you want to call it you should call it before committing response
According to [ServletResponse#reset](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#reset%28%29)

> Clears any data that exists in the buffer as well as the status code and headers. If the response has been committed, this method throws an IllegalStateException.